# How to change logo url

Tags: urls, logo

I want to know how to change the logo url of my website

https://thienthans.com/frenchies/

So when you click to the logo it will go directly to https://thienthans.com/example

Kindly help me, as I'm not a coder

Comment: It depends on your theme. Not all of them are coded the same way. Read up on your theme's documentation or ask the developer for support.

Comment: Hi. There is no thing about chaning the logo url in the document

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit the header.php of your theme and look for the code that outputs the logo link. Or you can try adding this to your theme's header.php file:

```
<script>
var yourElement = document.getElementById('sc_layouts_logo_1396606940');
yourElement.setAttribute('href', 'https://thienthans.com/example');
</script>
```